# How to get information from Linux continuously via Java, if there is a change in a directory?

Tags: java, linux

There are two directories with the same content (local directory and remote directory). sync files do when a change in one of the directories. I check directories continuously via Java and to get information for changes on  the directories. But I'm looking for an alternative way.

My question is;

> Does linux give informations for changes on a directory?

and if linux gives the information,

> How to get the information from Linux continuously via Java, if there is a change in a directory?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Java 6 (and therefore cannot use nio to watch a directory), you should take a look at [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/). It lets you watch directories for file changes. It works in Linux by providing a native library which uses [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).